# PDF Low-level: Invert colors within coordinates

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is it possible to invert the colors within a box (4 sets of coordinates) on a page from within the page's content object code?

My pages consist of simple B&W JBIG2 images and I wish to make the white black and the black white within a small box to highlight something.

Comment: Would extracting the images, manipulating the images according to your requirements with an image manipulation library, and re-insertion of the images be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mkl suggests, you may extract the images and change their bits - this might prove to be a little bit of work however. There might be another useful approach here, specifically useful because it would work regardless of what the underlying objects are.

It is possible in PDF to add a transparent object (for example a rectangle) over all underlying objects. In your case you would create a rectangle that you put on top of the images you already have in the page stream.

If you paint this rectangle in white, set it to transparent and choose "Difference" as the transparency blending mode, the net effect should be that the colors underneath your rectangle are inverted.

From the PDF specification: "Painting with white inverts the backdrop colour; painting with black produces no change."

This may be the quickest and most painless way to accomplish what you are looking for...